# Email rejected by Yahoo! but Android's Mail app keeps trying to resend

Tags: email, stock-email-app

I am using Android's Mail app on my Motorola DROID RAZR M for my Yahoo! account.  Last week, I tried to "reply to all" on an email that was sent to over 100 people and Yahoo! rejected it, claiming it was suspicious activity. That's okay, but the email is kept being resent. Every few minutes I get an error message on my phone saying that the email was not sent.

What I have tried:

1. I deleted it from the drafts folder in my Yahoo! account, but that didn't help.
2. I see the message in the "Outbox" but I can't do anything to it there. When I touch it, I get a message saying "Cannot open message. Message is currently being sent and is unable to be opened."
3. I stopped the app from running but it still won't let me do a/t to the email in the outbox.

How do I get my Razr to stop trying to resend the email?

Answer (score 0):

Your emails might be set up as "auto resend". Go into email options, and select none.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [the asker's (now deleted) comment](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/43118/email-rejected-by-yahoo-but-droid-keeps-trying-to-resend#comment58214_43118):

> I turned off mobile data and WiFi and then I was able to delete the email from the outbox. Looks like this worked.